# Problems related to shallow copy in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, stack, shallow-copy

I'm trying to understand the basics of C++ classes and the different forms of copying a class to another one, I made a simple class that use a table as a stack  and i created simple function for stacking/unstacking integers
pileInt.h :

```
class pile_entier{
    public:
        int* p;
        int n;
        int counter;
    
    public:
        //Constructeurs & Déstructeurs
        pile_entier(int n);
        pile_entier();
        ~pile_entier();
        //Les Méthodes
        void empile(int p);
        int depile();
        int pleine();
        int vide();
    
};
```

pileInt.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pileInt.h"

pile_entier::pile_entier(int l){
    n=l;
    p=new int [n];
    counter=0;
}
pile_entier::pile_entier(){
    n=20;
    p=new int [n];  
    counter=0;
}
pile_entier::~pile_entier(){
    delete[] p;
}
int pile_entier::pleine(){
    return counter ==n;
}
int pile_entier::vide(){
    return counter==0;
}
void pile_entier::empile(int i){
    if(pleine()){
        std::cerr << "La pile est pleine !" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    p[counter++]=i;
}
int pile_entier::depile(){
    if(vide()){
        std::cerr << "La pile est vide !" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return p[--counter];
}
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pileInt.h"
int main(void){
    pile_entier a(10);
    a.empile(1);
    a.empile(2);
    pile_entier b = a;

    std::cout << b.depile() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << a.depile() <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note : Some terms are in french as i study in french :
depile mean unsatck
empile mean stack
pile mean stack

Because i made a shallow copy the two should share the same table, thus unstacking 2 form the object b should affect a , witch if unstacked should give 1 because 2 is already unstacked by b.depile() but in my terminal it shows 2 2 rather than 2 1. I could'nt understand why ?

Comment: The stacks share the "table" (`*p`), but have different copies of `counter`. That soon makes them come out of phase, having different opinions on the stakc size.

Comment: @BoP what do you suggest to do so i make them share the counter ?

Comment: My suggestion would be "don't". Make a [proper deep copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you want to refer to the same object from different places, use a (smart) pointer or reference. I think your current code has a double-free problem when both destructors try to delete `p`. Lifetime and ownership issues will not have reasonable solutions around shallow-copying.

Comment: There is a reason C++ no longer recommends "raw pointers"  like `int* p;`. You will either have to make a choice, either you transfer ownership during copying and you have to use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or you make ownership shared and you have to use `std::shared_ptr`. Having to use `new/delete` in any newly written piece of C++ code is kind of a sign you are doing things wrong (unless you have a lot more experience).

Comment: "Ownership" in C++ means you have to make clear who is going to free the memory in the end.. so by making a copy of your `*p` you introduce a conflict, it will no longer be clear who has to call delete on it. If nobody does it you have memory leak, if both your class instances do it you will have a double free (which is not good either)

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: The posted answer already explains your actual problem, but in general, don't do this at all -- basically, std::vector exists to do dynamic arrays. Meddling with raw pointers in particular delete should raise all sorts alarm flags, and deserves an explanatory comment why you can't use things like std::vector or at least std::unique/shared_ptr.

Comment: I haven't needed to use a `new` or a `delete` in real production C++ code since 2010.  Use smart pointers and containers instead, and only use **non-owning** raw pointers.  (I consider `new` and `delete` to be advanced C++, and not anywhere near basic C++.)

Answer (score 0):

```
pile_entier b = a;
```

You now have two objects, `b` and `a`. Each one has its own `p`, its own `n`, and its own `counter`.

Modifying one of the object's `p`, `n`, or `counter`, has no effect, whatsoever, on the other one. They are two independent objects.

```
std::cout << b.depile() <<std::endl;
```

This modifies `b`'s `counter`.

```
std::cout << a.depile() <<std::endl;
```

And this will modify `a`'s `counter`. It has not been modified at all, and is still what it was. Why would it not? It's a completely different object.

Additionally, both objects have the same `p` pointer. At the end of `main()` both objects gets destroyed, and the class's destructor will attempt to `delete` the same pointer, twice. This will result in undefined behavior.

The reason for your confusion is that you were expecting objects in C++ to work like they do in Java or C#. You described how these objects will work in Java or C# (both `a` and `b` would, effectively, be the same object) but C++ is not Java or C#, and objects in C++ work in fundamentally different ways.

Comment: For them to be the same object, `pile_entier& b = a;`